# Spark: Splitting JSON strings into separate dataframe columns

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Im loading the below JSON string into a `dataframe` column.

```
{
    "title": {
        "titleid": "222",
        "titlename": "ABCD"
    },
    "customer": {
        "customerDetail": {
            "customerid": 878378743,
            "customerstatus": "ACTIVE",
            "customersystems": {
                "customersystem1": "SYS01",
                "customersystem2": null
            },
            "sysid": null
        },
        "persons": [{
            "personid": "123",
            "personname": "IIISKDJKJSD"
        },
        {
            "personid": "456",
            "personname": "IUDFIDIKJK"
        }]
    }
}

val js = spark.read.json("./src/main/resources/json/customer.txt")
println(js.schema)
val newDF = df.select(from_json($"value", js.schema).as("parsed_value"))
newDF.selectExpr("parsed_value.customer.*").show(false)
```

//Schema:

```
StructType(StructField(customer,StructType(StructField(customerDetail,StructType(StructField(customerid,LongType,true), StructField(customerstatus,StringType,true), StructField(customersystems,StructType(StructField(customersystem1,StringType,true), StructField(customersystem2,StringType,true)),true), StructField(sysid,StringType,true)),true), StructField(persons,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(personid,StringType,true), StructField(personname,StringType,true)),true),true)),true), StructField(title,StructType(StructField(titleid,StringType,true), StructField(titlename,StringType,true)),true))
```

//Output:

```
+------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
|customerDetail                |persons                                |
+------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
|[878378743, ACTIVE, [SYS01,],]|[[123, IIISKDJKJSD], [456, IUDFIDIKJK]]|
+------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

My Question: Is there a way that I can split the key value as a `separate dataframe columns` like below
by keeping the `Array columns` as is since I need to have only `one record per json string`:

Example for `customer column`:

```
customer.customerDetail.customerid,customer.customerDetail.customerstatus,customer.customerDetail.customersystems.customersystem1,customer.customerDetail.customersystems.customersystem2,customerid,customer.customerDetail.sysid,customer.persons
878378743,ACTIVE,SYS01,null,null,{"persons": [ { "personid": "123", "personname": "IIISKDJKJSD" }, { "personid": "456", "personname": "IUDFIDIKJK" } ] }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited post** :

```
val df = spark.read.json("your/path/data.json")
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
def collectFields(field: String, sc: DataType): Seq[String] = {
  sc match {
    case sf: StructType => sf.fields.flatMap(f => collectFields(field+"."+f.name, f.dataType))
    case _ => Seq(field)
  }
}

val fields = collectFields("",df.schema).map(_.tail)

df.select(fields.map(col):_*).show(false)
```

Output :

```
+----------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-------------------------------------+-------+---------+
|customerid|customerstatus|customersystem1|customersystem2|sysid|persons                              |titleid|titlename|
+----------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-------------------------------------+-------+---------+
|878378743 |ACTIVE        |SYS01          |null           |null |[[123,IIISKDJKJSD], [456,IUDFIDIKJK]]|222    |ABCD     |
+----------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-----+-------------------------------------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need only one record by keeping the `arrays as is` so `no Explode`. And I don't want to give all the column names explicitly for selecting since there could be hundreds.

Comment: @Leibnitz thanks for your feedback. Just updated my answer to fit your needs. I created a basic recursive function to find nested fields for StructTypes.

Comment: Thank you for your time! This works well @@baitmbarek

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the help of RDD's by defining column names in an empty RDD and then reading json,converting it to DataFrame with .toDF() and iterating it to the empty RDD.